# Using preg_match to find a group in a string?

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm trying to find special characters with characters like `<?`, `<?php`, or `?>` in a string. The code below works to find "php" in the string anywhere no matter if it's `PHP`, `php`, or `phpaPHPa`.

```
<?php
$searchfor = "php";
$string = "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.";
if (preg_match("/".$searchfor."/i", $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

I need a similar code that finds special characters like `<?`, `<?php`, or `?>` in the string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same code. Just make sure to escape regex special characters when using them in matching. The question mark must be escaped so your `$searchfor` becomes `<\?php`

Comment: That was simple! I was just reading and learning about regex. Thanks for the help. Now I can finish building this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

Using [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) (or [stripos](https://www.php.net/stripos)) will be faster than using RegEx'es...

```
if(false === strpos($text, '<?'))
  echo 'Match was not found';
else
  echo 'Match was found';
```

Comment: No. strpos doesn't find grouped words good. halfdan was spot on.